# SQL error code: 1364 Field 'CustomerNumber' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
CustomerNumber int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerFirstName char(30) NOT NULL,
CustomerLastName char(30) NOT NULL,
Phone char(12) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ENROLLMENT( 
CourseNumber int NOT NULL, 
CustomerNumber int NOT NULL, 
AmountPaid float(2) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT pk_ENROLLMENT PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNumber, CourseNumber),
CONSTRAINT ENROLLMENTS_fk FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNumber) 
    REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerNumber), 
CONSTRAINT fk_ENROLLMENT FOREIGN KEY (CourseNumber) 
    REFERENCES COURSE(CourseNumber) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
); 

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CustomerNumber, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, Phone)
VALUES (992, 'Steve', 'Johnson', '631-998-2244');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CustomerNumber, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, Phone)
VALUES (998, 'Jane', 'Lovegood', '516-777-0033');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CustomerNumber, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, Phone)
VALUES (987, 'John', 'Lovegood', '516-777-2888');

INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT(CourseNumber)
SELECT CourseNumber
FROM COURSE
WHERE Course = 'Statistics' LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT(CustomerNumber, AmountPaid)
SELECT CustomerNumber, 600.00
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CustomerLastName = 'Johnson' LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It looks like the problem might be in the part that adds the enrollment.  You add a row with only coursenumber, and then add another different row with only customernumber and amountpaid.  Those data should probably all go into the same row.

Comment: What is the structure of ENROLLMENT?

Comment: @JacobH `CREATE TABLE ENROLLMENT(
CourseNumber int NOT NULL,
CustomerNumber int NOT NULL,
AmountPaid float(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_ENROLLMENT PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNumber, CourseNumber),
CONSTRAINT ENROLLMENTS_fk FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNumber)
REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerNumber),
CONSTRAINT fk_ENROLLMENT FOREIGN KEY (CourseNumber)
REFERENCES COURSE(CourseNumber)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
);`

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Your INSERT doesn't specify any value for the CustomerNumber column, and that column is NOT NULL and has no default value.

Comment: @jarlh adding a default value does not work

Comment: If I were to guess, you've got an XY Problem where you want to insert 3 values into ENROLLMENT but you're trying to do it in 2 queries when you really need 1 query with a JOIN. Since the three fields you are inserting into are all specified as `NOT NULL` you can't do 2 separate inserts.

Comment: @james I tried to put it in the same row but I am not sure how to do it because I get error messages if I try to add two tables at the same time

Comment: No, a default value for a PK/FK makes no sense. You need to know what you're doing, specify the value!

Comment: Is there a key between COURSE and CUSTOMER?

Comment: @jacobh there is no key between course and customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables that contain the data and provide one complete row to the INSERT INTO statement.  You can't do two separate inserts because of the constraints on the columns.

```
INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT(CourseNumber, CustomerNumber, AmountPaid)
  SELECT COURSE.CourseNumber, CUSTOMER.CustomerNumber, 600.00
  FROM COURSE
  LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER on CUSTOMER.CustomerLastName='Johnson'
  WHERE COURSE.Course = 'Statistics' LIMIT 1;
```

To me this screams out "oh but what if two customers have the same last name", that will be a problem.

Comment: Also what if two courses are called "Statistics". But you got my upvote because this problem is solved. We can't fix OP's data or structure we can only make suggestions...